# From yfinance to manipulate dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

Hello i'm new to python and pandas and i need some help with manipulating yfinance dataframe output

i'm trying to scrape some market data from yahoo finance with yfinance with this code:

```
data = yf.download("DYAN.JK CENT.JK", start="2015-01-01", 
                   end="2018-12-31", interval="1mo", group_by='tickers')
```

and get this dataframe output:

```
             DYAN.JK                                              CENT.JK
Date         Open   High    Low  Close   Adj Close       Volume   Open        High        Low        Close
2015-01-01   138.0  142.0  121.0  121.0  118.931625   37380000.0  158.462952  167.222214  155.277771 155.277771  ... 
2015-02-01   122.0  142.0  110.0  122.0  119.914528  375925600.0  155.277771  156.870361  155.277771 155.277771  ... 
2015-03-01   121.0  123.0  102.0  103.0  101.239319   70775500.0  155.277771  155.277771  131.388885 155.277771  ... 
2015-04-01   105.0  107.0   74.0   76.0   74.700851   62136500.0  155.277771  155.277771  128.203705 151.296295  ... 
...          ...    ...    ...    ...    ...     ...  ...         ...         ...         ...
```

and i wanna know how i can use pandas melt to manipulate the dataframe to this format:

```
Date       Ticker  Open   High   Low    Close  Adj Close   Volume
2015-01-01 DYAN.JK 138.0  142.0  121.0  121.0  118.931625   37380000.0
2015-02-01 DYAN.JK 122.0  142.0  110.0  122.0  119.914528  375925600.0
2015-03-01 DYAN.JK 121.0  123.0  102.0  103.0  101.239319   70775500.0
...        ...     ...    ...    ...    ...    ...         ...
2015-01-01 CENT.JK 158    167    155    155    ...         ...
2015-02-01 CENT.JK 155    156    155    155    ...         ...
2015-03-01 CENT.JK 155    155    131    155    ...         ...
...        ...     ...    ...    ...    ...    ...         ...
```

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
data.stack(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Ticker'})
```

Comment: thank you very much it workedd! saved me a lot of time 